# Create Real-Time Mobile Client Location Tracking ASP.NET Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr, real-time

I have an **asp.net mvc web app** and want to add a section that can be able to track live location of some Persons who have an android app on thier smartphone and show them on map. I want to know what libraries are required to implement?

For instance, can I use **SignalR** and If yes, can I use it in mvc, how can get the location and What needs to be done in the mobile app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can do this with SignalR, you can start with the articles here : http://jbeckwith.com/2011/10/12/building-a-user-map-with-signalr-and-bing/

Comment: I saw this article، but I need a better source or sample to know how to use signalr with the mobile app